# Nestjs - Unit testing for a controller that is inherited from CrudController

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, nestjs

I am doing a unit testing script for a controller file for an API called promotions.controller.ts. However, I am not sure why my controller file is not instantiating the service file that I mock using jest in its constructor and throwing the error of:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined.**

findOne is one of the function that exist in my promotions.service.ts and it is also extended from a CrudService which is a parent class of this service.

I have already tried to mock a class and spyOn to mock the PromotionService but it is still not working.

This is the code for **promotions.controller.spec.ts**:

```
import { PromotionsService } from "../promotions.service";
import {PromotionsController} from "../promotions.controller"
import { Test, TestingModule } from "@nestjs/testing"
import {OrganizationsService} from "../../organizations/organizations.service"

describe('PromotionsController', () => {
    let promotionsController: PromotionsController;
    let promotionsService: PromotionsService;

    jest.mock("../promotions.service");

    const mockOrganizationsService = {
    }

    const mockPromotionsService = {
        
    };
    

    beforeEach(async () => {
      const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
          controllers: [PromotionsController],
          providers:[PromotionsService,OrganizationsService]
        }).overrideProvider(PromotionsService).useValue(mockPromotionsService)
          .overrideProvider(OrganizationsService).useValue(mockOrganizationsService)
          .compile();
  
      promotionsService = moduleRef.get<PromotionsService>(PromotionsService);
      promotionsController = moduleRef.get<PromotionsController>(PromotionsController);

      const promotions = await promotionsController.performDelete({id:'1234'});
    });
  
    describe('promotionsController', () => {

      it('controller should be defined', async () => {
        expect(promotionsController).toBeDefined();
      });

      it('service should be defined', async () => {
        expect(promotionsService).toBeDefined();
      });

      it('promotionsController should be calling performDelete', async () => {
        expect(promotionsController.performDelete({id:'1234'})).not.toEqual(null);
        expect(promotionsService.find).toHaveBeenCalled();
      })

    });
  });
```

This is the code at my **promotions.controller.ts**:

```
import { Controller } from '@nestjs/common';
import {ApiBearerAuth} from "@nestjs/swagger";
import {Crud} from "../ms-common/utils/crud/crud.decorator";
import {Promotion} from "./promotions.model";
import {PromotionsDto} from "./dto/promotions.dto";
import {CrudController} from "../ms-common/utils/crud/crud.controller";
import {PromotionsService} from "./promotions.service";
import {OrganizationsService} from "../organizations/organizations.service";

@ApiBearerAuth()
@Crud({
  model: Promotion,
  routes: {
    create: {dto: PromotionsDto},
    update: {dto: PromotionsDto},
  },
})

@Controller('promotions')
export class PromotionsController extends CrudController {
  constructor(public model: PromotionsService, private organization: OrganizationsService) {
    super(model);
  }

  async performDelete(id) {
    const instance = await this.model.findOne({id});
    await this.organization.sbQueue({
      type: "promotion",
      ids: [id],
      delete: true,
      organization: instance.organization,
    });
    return super.performDelete(id);
  }
}
```

Anyone knows how should I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, we need to wait for the controller to instantiate the constructor since it is an asynchronous process. Hence adding await and resolve into the code help solve the problem.

The code below is how I instantiate the controller:

`organizationsController = await moduleRef.resolve<OrganizationsController>(OrganizationsController);`